# C# Fields.Update not working

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm converting an old`ish VB application to C#. This is a trim-down of the converted method (Logging, error handling, etc removed):

```
Word.Document oDoc = new Word.Document();
Word.Application oWord = null;

//'Use Passed Word Application ELSE Open new Word Application.
oWord = WordInstance ?? new Word.Application { Visible = false };

//'Call Property Updating Method
oWord = UpdateProperties(ref oWord, ref oDoc);

//'Refresh All Fields
try { oDoc.Fields.Update(); } catch { }

//'Print
oWord.PrintOut(
    Background: false,
    Copies: QueueDetail.Copies
);
```

The documents being worked with have CustomeDocumentProperties added to them as a previous step (foreach row in database table => add CustomDocumentProperty).

`UpdateProperties()` pulls data from a DB and updates those CustomDocumentProperties (foreach CustomProperty in document => Set Value from Database).

From what I can see the properties are getting updated. I can do a `foreach` to print all the Custom Properties and the `Name/Value`s match up to whats expected. I can save the document and the fields are either updated, or can be updated via right-click => update field.

The issue is that it seems that only half of the fields are getting updated via `oDoc.Fields.Update();`. (hence the need to save file and right click `update field` to verify that the data is actually in the field).

So something on the document like this, where each block is a FIELD:

```
LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME MI
ADDRESS
CITY, STATE ZIP
HOMEPHONE
```

Gets updated to:

```
Public, John Q
1234 Never Never Lane
CITY, STATE ZIP
HOMEPHONE
```

In the previous program, this seems to work without issue. Everything else so far has been stuff I can solve with minimal issue (VB to C# changes mainly and a change of logging to Log4net).

How can I troubleshoot why `Fields.Update()` isn't updating all the fields? It's in a try/catch and doesn't throw any errors. Everything before (fields HAVE the data in them) and after (document prints with fields not updated) seems fine...)

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

```
//'Use Passed Word Application ELSE Open new Word Application.
oWord = this.oWord ?? new Word.Application { Visible = false };

//'Call Property Updating Method
oWord = UpdateProperties(ref oWord, ref oDoc);

//'Call PrePrint Function (if existing)
try { oWord.Run("PrePrint"); } catch { }

//'Refresh All Fields try { oDoc.Fields.Update(); } catch { }
foreach (Field field in oDoc.Fields)
    field.Update();

//'Refresh All Shapes
foreach (Shape shape in oDoc.Shapes)
    shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update();

// Print Document
Print(oWord);
```

Issue is that groupings/text boxes needed to be updated via Shapes. First field.Update() doesn't catch them all.